# Grid-Area span not working with rows that fill the whole container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the following code I need boxes 1 and 2 to both take up 2 columns and 2 rows while the row-line and column-line start values remain at auto. Like this:

grid-area: auto / auto / span 2 / span 2;

Everything works great when there are 4 columns or 3 columns, but as soon as I reduce the number of columns to 2, boxes 1 and 2 no longer take up 2 rows as indicated that they should by the span property. They only take up 1 row, even though the span is set to 2 rows. Am I missing something here? To see what im talking about, run this code as is. Then add one more "auto" to the grid-template-columns property and run it again. You will see that boxes 1 and 2 now behave properly.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: auto / auto / span 2 / span 2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The grid row will only span over two rows - if there is two rows to span over (i.e. if you add the extra `auto` to `grid-template-columns` it will have two rows to span over (item 1 => item 3 & 4 and item 2 => item 5 & 6). I suggest you define the height of the row instead (`.item1`, `.item2`), since it's more logical as well.

Comment: I don't understand. There are 2 rows for it to span over...Just the ones you mentioned...How does adding an extra column make there be enough rows to span over? It just adds a column.

Comment: _It doesn't work because `grid-template-rows` isn't defined._ It can't just auto generate them based on the number of grid-items and their layout.

Comment: Ah! Thank you VXp and Tibbelit. I got it working!